# Security vulnerbility in Python library?

Tags: python, security

Is there any known security vulnerabilities regarding Python or its libraries?

Thanks,

Comment: Good question, I am looking for answers too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [there are a few](http://bugs.python.org/issue?%40search_text=&ignore=file%3Acontent&title=&%40columns=title&id=&%40sort=activity&type=4&%40group=priority&status=1&%40action=search).

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for them right now.